# Python Guess Who not working correctly?

Tags: python

I am currently dabbling in Python and was doing a "Guess Who" game as sort of a warm up to this coding language. However, I am running into an issue. It seems like my "properties" of my "Character" class are not being properly identified and it is failing to ever get the character right, except for pure luck. What can I do with the code I have to try and get this miniature version working?Most of the print functions were just me trying to trouble shoot, and see how the code was actually working.

```
#attempt at Guess Who!

import random

class Character:
    def __init__(self, g, h, e, s, n):
        self.hasGlasses = g
        self.hairColor = h
        self.eyeColor = e
        self.gender = s
        self.name = n

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, {},  {} eyes, {} glasses, {} hair".format(self.name, self.gender, self.eyeColor, self.hasGlasses, self.hairColor)

    def checkEC(self, x):
        result = False
        if (self.eyeColor.lower() == str(x).lower()):
            result = False
        return result

    def checkGlasses(self, x):
        result = False
        if (self.hasGlasses.lower() == str(x).lower()):
            result = True
        return result

    def checkHC(self, x):
        result = False
        if (self.hairColor.lower() == str(x).lower()):
            result = True
        return result

    def checkG(self, x):
        result = False
        if (self.gender.lower() == str(x).lower()):
            result = True
        return result

possibleChars = []

rob = Character("yes", "blonde", "green", "boy", "Rob")
possibleChars.append(rob)
susan = Character("no", "red", "blue", "girl", "Susan")
possibleChars.append(susan)
pat = Character("no", "brown", "brown", "boy", "Pat")
possibleChars.append(pat)
shane = Character("no", "brown", "blue", "boy", "Shane")
possibleChars.append(shane)
ben = Character("no", "blonde", "green", "boy", "Ben")
possibleChars.append(ben)
angello = Character("yes", "blonde", "hazel", "girl", "Angelica")
possibleChars.append(angello)
questions = ["What color is your hair? ", "Do you wear glasses? ", "Are you a boy or a girl? ",
"What color are your eyes? "
];

counter = 0
guessed = False
qsAsked = []
charsLeft = []
for i in possibleChars:
    print(i)


while not guessed:
    y = random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)
    print(int(y))

    if (counter == 0):

        if (y in qsAsked):
            guessed = False

        elif(y == 0):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in possibleChars:
                if (character.checkHC(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.append(character)
            qsAsked.append(0)
            for i in possibleChars:
                print(i)
            counter = counter + 1


        elif(y == 1):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in possibleChars:
                if (character.checkGlasses(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.append(character)
            qsAsked.append(1)
            for i in possibleChars:
                print(i)
            counter = counter + 1

        elif(y == 2):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in possibleChars:
                if (character.checkG(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.append(character)
            qsAsked.append(2)
            for i in possibleChars:
                print(i)
            counter = counter + 1

        elif(y == 3):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in possibleChars:
                if (character.checkEC(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.append(character)
            qsAsked.append(3)
            for i in possibleChars:
                print(i)
            counter = counter + 1

    elif (counter > 0) :
        if (y in qsAsked):
            guessed = False

        elif(y == 0):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in charsLeft:
                if (not character.checkHC(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.remove(character)
            if (len(charsLeft) == 1):
                print("Your character must be {}!".format(charsLeft[0]))
                guessed = True
            qsAsked.append(0)
            for i in charsLeft:
                print(i)



        elif(y == 1):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in charsLeft:
                if (not character.checkGlasses(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.remove(character)
            if (len(charsLeft) == 1):
                print("Your character must be {}!".format(charsLeft[0]))
                guessed = True
            qsAsked.append(1)
            for i in charsLeft:
                print(i)

        elif(y == 2):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in charsLeft:
                if (not character.checkG(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.remove(character)
            if (len(charsLeft) == 1):
                print("Your character must be {}!".format(charsLeft[0]))
                guessed = True
            qsAsked.append(2)
            for i in charsLeft:
                print(i)


        elif(y == 3):
            x = input(questions[int(y)])
            for character in charsLeft:
                if (not character.checkEC(str(x))):
                    charsLeft.remove(character)
            if (len(charsLeft) == 1):
                print("Your character must be {}!".format(charsLeft[0]))
                guessed = True
            qsAsked.append(3)
            for i in charsLeft:
                print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program contains two serious errors:

1. The method checkEC always returns False.  The second `result = False` in that function should be `result = True`.
2. In the `elif counter == 0:` block of the while loop, you are trying to remove an item from a list while iterating over it.  That doesn't work and Python doesn't warn you.  What you can do instead is: make a new list as you step through the old one, and then set the old list variable name to point to the new list when you're finished.  To illustrate that I rewrote that section as follows:

   ```
   elif (counter > 0) :
       if y in qsAsked:
           continue
       x = input(questions[y])
       left = []
       for character in charsLeft:
           if y == 0:
               b = character.checkHC(x)
           elif y == 1:
               b = character.checkGlasses(x)
           elif y == 2:
               b = character.checkG(x)
           else:
               b = character.checkEC(x)
           if b:
               left.append(character)
       if len(left) == 1:
           print("Your character must be {}!".format(left[0]))
           guessed = True
       qsAsked.append(y)
       for i in left:
           print(i)
       charsLeft = left
   ```

I make a new list ("left") and append each character that is left.  If `left` doesn't have a length of 1, I reassign `charsLeft` to point to it.  The next time through the loop, charsLeft will have all the remaining characters in it, just like it did in your version.

Your program was repetitious, so in my rewrite I have factored out the statements that occurred over and over again.  It's much shorter now.  Some other things to note, which make the code easier to read:

- In Python, if statements don't need parenthesis.
- If a variable is already an int, there's no point in wrapping it in the int function.
- If a variable is already a string, there's no point in wrapping it in the str function.
- I use a `continue` statement to bounce back up to the top of the while loop if the question has been asked before.

Some problems with your program as it stands:

- If there's only one character left after the first question, the program asks a second question anyway.
- If the user makes a typo or enters the wrong thing, no characters will match.  There is no recovery from this situation and the program just keeps on asking silly questions with no hope of success.